# query execution taking more time

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Below query taking fourteen seconds to give result.Is there any way to optimize this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.F_T_CODE AS F_T_CODE, PHT.F_PHRAS AS F_PHRAS FROM PHRASE_LINK L 
INNER JOIN PHRAS_TR PHT  ON L.F_P_ID = PHT.F_P_ID 
WHERE  PHT.F_PHRAS LIKE '%a%' 
AND PHT.F_LAN = 'EN' AND L.F_D_CODE != L.F_T_CODE ORDER BY PHT.F_PHRAS
OFFSET 100000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause has `LIKE '%a%'`, which won't work with an index.  You could try indexing the join columns, but I'm not even sure SQL Server would choose to use them.  So, I don't see any way to speed up your query.

Comment: It is kind of hard to give any advice without knowing the table definitions, indexes etc.. Please add that

Comment: index is available for PHT.F_P_ID BUT NOT AVAILABLE FOR L.F_P_ID on Join condition
index is  available for PHT.F_PHRAS column in like operator
index is available for L.F_D_CODE AND L.F_T_Code columns

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Query by using INNER JOIN on same table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.F_T_CODE AS F_T_CODE, PHT.F_PHRAS AS F_PHRAS 
FROM PHRASE_LINK L
INNER JOIN PHRASE_LINK L1 ON L.F_D_CODE != L1.F_T_CODE
INNER JOIN PHRAS_TR PHT  ON L.F_P_ID = PHT.F_P_ID 
WHERE  PHT.F_PHRAS LIKE '%a%' `enter code here`
AND PHT.F_LAN = 'EN'  ORDER BY PHT.F_PHRAS
OFFSET 100000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thank you.But it also takes some time.